# Can one clicker be used for two animals?

Tags: cats, dogs, clicker-training

We have a cat and he’s clicker-trained to a certain degree, at least enough to understand that the clicker means he’s doing something right and to expect a treat. The training sessions for the cat are rare-ish, mostly to reinforce the existing commands and to keep him entertained when the weather is bad and he stays inside. He also knows and reacts to a “spoken” click command (similar to a tongue-click).

In the nearer future, we are expecting the arrival of a dog puppy which shall be clicker-trained as well - and especially in the early phase there will be lots of clicks as puppy has a lot to learn.

Do we have to get a different clicker with a different sound, or can the same be used for training both? Will using the same lead to confusion in the animal that’s not “actively trained” at that moment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should definitely get a different clicker.

Clicker training works by connecting the sound of a clicker to a positive outcome. If the cat hears the clicker, but doesn't get a treat, you basically desensitize him, meaning the actual clicker training won't work as well in the future.

To be honest, you don't even need a clicker, you just need a very consistent sound. Most dog owners just say "good boy", which is enough for training. But since everyone uses those words, dogs can get confused in dog parks and similar places. To be absolutely sure, your sound should be unique. Saying other words (even in a different language) or creating a different sound is ok. You can just as well use other objects that make sounds, like some small children's toys or whatever you find at home.

Comment: Thanks, my thoughts went along these lines as well, just wanted more input from users with more experience - I never had more than one pet at a time. We’ll probably do some research on other clicker models or alternatives, simply because I don’t want to make it extra hard on a puppy to learn *four* affirmative sounds in one go - same word spoken by different family members. And it’s pretty impossible to have just one family member involved initially.